# GWT confusion for a startup web app. (beginner level)

Tags: gwt

I've been trying to learn GWT for quite a while, I want to build a website that is somewhat advance for my level.

I looked at a lot of documentations/books/blogs/videos, and I just keep getting more confused. Mainly due to facing new frameworks/methods/tools ... etc. in building apps using GWT.

For instance I'm having difficulty answering these questions:

1- Should I use Spring Roo/ SpringSource Tool Suite?

2- What sort of database specification/implementation should I use (JDO, JPA.. I'm a noob when it comes to Java DB issues)?

3- Should I use Google App Engine platform, how easy/useful it is for a start-up project?

4- Should I start coding now, or continue reading and confusing myself (I've started on my POJO data model)?

5- Communicating with the server, RPC or RequestFactory or something else?

Sorry for the many questions, as you can see I don't have much experience in GWT but I'm welling to challenge myself, I just need some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: start simple, plain GWT (RPC since it's easier to figure out than RequestFactory), and once you feel comfortable move on to the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking each question in turn...

1. To start with no, its extra setting up and its sometimes nicer to be in control of your code and know exactly what is in there.
2. I would go for JPA with GWT as it is supported by Google App Engine. But bear in mind GAE doesn't provide a relational database and there are quite a lot of restrictions on on what is and isn'ty supported. If you're not using GAE then JPA or JDO are as good as each other.
3. If you're planning on using Google App Engine then use it from day one and design your app to take advantage of its facilities. If you are going to use this then I would suggest [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) for your object mapping/"database" implementation as opposed to JPA/JDO as it's a more natural fit.
4. Yep, start coding now but don't expect the confusion to stop.
5. I would give the vanilla GWT RPC a go to see what you are dealing with, then try [GWT Dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) or the newer [GWT Platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) which make the whole RPC mechanism much simpler to deal. RequestFactory is fine too but has some idiosyncrasies that take some getting used to. In the end the choice will largely be personal - they all do the job and do it well.
6. Other suggestions

   1. use activities and places to control application navigation
   2. event bus for event propagation and to keep your code decoupled
   3. MVP to separate logic/view
   4. dependency injection (Gin client side, Guice server side) to glue it all together

Comment: I forgot to say thank you, so thank you very much for your help.